# Как пропинговать адрес в простейшем случае?

Tags: delphi, tcp-ip, ping

Доброго времени суток! Пробовал найти материал по пингованию сети. Подскажите куском кода, как пропинговать адрес в простейшем случае?

Comment: первая ссылка в гугле по сабжу не подошла?

Comment: есть компоненты для работы с сетью, и среди них есть специально для пингования. Я бы посоветовал библиотеку компонентов IP*Works.
там есть компонент IPWPing, которым я и пользовался...

Answer (score 1):

Например так:

```
WinExec(pchar('ping.exe sources.ru'), sw_show);
```

Comment: спасибо. Это вызов внешнего приложения, а как сделать самому пинги, например через icmp?

Answer (score 0):

Я как-то использовал это:

[код процедурки](http://delphiworld.narod.ru/base/console_to_memo.html),
а делее:

```
RunDosInMemo('Ping '+'www.ru', Memo1);
```